# Database connection issues with Maria DB

Tags: php, mariadb, frontend, dreamweaver

**TLDR**:I am trying to design the front end GUI for the website,
using PHP (Version 7.2.1) and adobe Dreamweaver CS 6 (Version 12.0 build 5808).
It is showing only MySQL database connection option.I need to connect to the Maria DB database.
Do I need adobe CC 2017/18? Can I connect the design and the database using sublime text/Text pad++ instead? If not,any free/90 day trial software I can use?

**More details:**
Dreamweaver is showing *'Your PhP server doesn't have the MySQl module loaded.....'error.*

I am VERY new at this.My task is designing a webform (registering name,age,address etc.)with database using PhP and MariaDB.(MUST use this 2).Learning about php just using W3school and youtube so far.

I am using Navicat premium (Version 12.0.24,64 bit) as DB administration tool to connect to mariaDB.
Xampp's MySQl\bin\mysql.exe shows that my Maria DB server version is 10.1.30, connection ID is 4,and when I update the table in Navicat,the localhost PhPmyadmin page shows the updated table.
Xampp control panel version 3.2.2.On Windows 10 Education 64bit

Comment: Maria uses the same drivers / PHP modules as MySQL. The PHP _mysql_ module was removed in PHP 7. Use `pdo_mysql` or the _mysqli_ module instead

Comment: Thanks !I used 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crud"); 
to connect